# Story about a man going insane because of his obession with computer c.50s-60s?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a story a few months back and I cannot remember where or how I found it and it's been bugging me for days. I'll list the things that I can remember.

- The main character is a man who is working with a computer. The computer has a "female" sounding name, and I think it's referred to as a "she" in the story. It was something like "CASELA," some kind of typical, all-caps, 3-syllable computer name.
- Something about working with the computer is causing the man to go insane and lose his grip on reality. I seem to remember that it's mentioned that his wife has noticed he is changing. I THINK he's becoming obsessed and falling in love with the computer. Perhaps the computer is referred to as a god, or better than god, or something along those lines.
- At some point in the story the computer creates a message (printed or displayed or something) that is all gibberish, but it is then decoded to say something like "[computer name] DESTROY DESTROY DESTROY." The decoding of the message seemed to be fairly easy, like they were all capital letters in a paragraph, or something.
- To the best of my recollection, it was only about a dozen pages long or so.
- If it helps, I'm pretty certain that the story had a Wikipedia page.
- I'm almost certain that the computer was being used by the military, and had the capability to destroy mankind.

Comment: Did you read it online, in an ebook, in a (physical) book or in a magazine?

Comment: I read it online, and I feel like it was simply direct scans of the book or magazine it was published in, and it's possible it was on archive.org.

Comment: Hmm. Any chance that it was the computer that was falling in love with him? I'm almost remembering one that might match...

Comment: It's not ringing a bell for me, but it's possible. His delusion and obsession definitely was controlled by the computer, but I believe it was more interested in world domination/destruction than love...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wow. So after about a week of digging and searching I just found it by going through a list of short SF stories by year.

It was "[Dulcie and Decorum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dulcie_and_Decorum)" by Damon Knight!

Amazingly, my memories were far closer to "From Agnes--With Love" as suggested by Keith, which I haven't seen in years. No idea how it got that far from the actual story.

Answer (score 6):

That sounds very much like the 1964 Twilight Zone episode ["From Agnes - with Love"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0734571/), starring Wally Cox.

Wally Cox's character, James Elwood is brought in to replace a previous programmer who went insane after interacting with the computer, named Agnes. Agnes starts offering Elwood advice about his co-worker Millie.

> The "advice" is designed to spoil Elwood's relationship with Millie so that Agnes can have him to herself.

I don't know whether the story has been published in written form, but I wouldn't be at all surprised if it has. Perhaps that's where you encountered it.

Agnes displays a few messages that appear to be gibberish, but are actually Latin and Russian; see http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0734571/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv.

(Incidentally, that episode has an unintentionally hilarious line. When James Elwood is told about a problem with Agnes's operation, he says "Probably her subroutines need debugging.")

Comment: It's similar for sure, but unfortunately I couldn't find any indication anywhere that it was originally a short story or based on one (other than "EPICAC" by Vonnegut, which it seems almost lifted from)...

Comment: @hytone: EPICAC was also done on TV with Bill Bixby. http://www.tcm.com/tcmdb/title/477413/Rex-Harrison-Presents-Short-Stories-of-Love/